# Only Crashlytics data is migrated from Fabric to Firebase, Analytics data isn't migrated

Tags: android, firebase, google-fabric

I migrated our previous crash data attained from Fabric to Firebase a few days ago.  Firebase is now displaying the crashlytics related data from Fabric, however, the data related to analytics(latest release, retention etc.) is nowhere to be found.

Fabric shows the data has been migrated successfully on both OS(Android, iOS) but only our Android OS is showing this problem
(I can find analytics data for our  iOS OS in Firebase)

In addition, I found out that the Firebase analytics library was not imported on our Android Application.
After importing and integrating the library I am now able to view the analytics related data provided by Firebase.
But the problem of the migrated Fabric Analytics data being absent is still present.

Is there possible way to find and see the analytics data(migrated from Fabric) for our Android OS?

Answer (score 0):

Great question!Your Answers metrics and events data will not be transferred from the Fabric dashboard to the Firebase console. In order to continue getting similar metrics and more from the Firebase console, as well as the crash-free users statistic you're used to seeing in Fabric, I recommend that you install [Google Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics) in your app. Firebase will no longer process any incoming Answers data or display it, but it will not cause any crashes in your app or affect your end-users.

Comment: This is a horrible experience, all the main documentation for the migration said that no other changes were required except migration. I'm appalled that I need to go back and update all my existing apps for what was marketed as a like-to-like upgrade.